# python get module name that declared a variable

Tags: python, module

so classes in python can tell you where they were defined:

```py
# module a.py
class Something:
  pass
```

```py
from a import SomeClass

print(f"name: {SomeClass.__name__}, module: {SomeClass.__module__}")
# name: SomeClass, module: a
```

I want to know if it is possible to get the module that declared a variable, rather than a class.

```py
# module a.py
SOME_LIST = [1,2,3]
```

```py
from a import SOME_LIST

# something like this:
print(SOME_LIST.__module__)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "b.py", line 3, in <module>
#     print(SOME_LIST.__module__)
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

The use case is that I need to crawl a complicated structure of nested classes and lists across many files and I need to generate namespaces for classes and variables found in this structure.